# ArrayList is being initialised everytime the CustomDialogFragment is opened

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I use Arraylist in CustomDialogFragment to store values each time when the user checks a checkbox. And removes the values when the user unchecks it. The issue is that each time the user dismisses the dialog, the values in the arraylist gets deleted. I think it's because of reinitialisation of the array  each time when the user  opens the dialog.

I was thinking to store the array in shared preferences, but not sure whether that is the right way to do it. Kindly suggest me how to do it effectively.

**CarTypeDialogFragment.java**

```
public class CarTypeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public interface OnInputListener {
    void sendInput(String input);
}

public OnInputListener mOnInputListener;

CheckBox type1, type2, type4;
String SedanCheckBoxesVal, SUVCheckBoxesVal, HatchBackCheckBoxesVal;

ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
View v;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        //totalCars = getArguments().getString("cars","");
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (v != null) {
        if ((ViewGroup) v.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        return v;
    }
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restype_dialog, container, false);


    type1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    type1.setChecked(getFromSP("cb1"));

    type2 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    type2.setChecked(getFromSP("cb2"));

    type4 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    type4.setChecked(getFromSP("cb4"));

    type1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                SedanCheckBoxesVal = "'Accord','Avlon','Challenger'";
                saveInSp("cb1", true);
                myList.add(SedanCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                saveInSp("cb1enable", false);

            } else {
                myList.remove(SedanCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                saveInSp("cb1", false);
            }
         }
    });


    type2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //is chkIos checked?

            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                SUVCheckBoxesVal = "'GMC','BMW'";
                saveInSp("cb2", true);
                myList.add(SUVCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                saveInSp("cb2enable", false);

            } else {
                myList.remove(SUVCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                saveInSp("cb2", false);
            }
        }
    });


    type4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //is chkIos checked?

            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                HatchBackCheckBoxesVal = "'Polo','Micra','MiniCooper'";
                saveInSp("cb4", true);
                myList.add(HatchBackCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                saveInSp("cb4enable", false);
                type4.setEnabled(false);

            } else {
                myList.remove(HatchBackCheckBoxesVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join("", myList));
                mOnInputListener.sendInput("");
                saveInSp("cb4", false);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}

private boolean getFromSP(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
    windowParams.dimAmount = 0.00f;
    windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(windowParams);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    //workaround for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423 (unable to retain instance after configuration change)
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is okay to save your string list to `SharedPreferences` considering you're not saving a lot of data.

In this case it is okay to save your list in `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `ArrayList` is re-initialized to be empty whenever you close and reopen the dialog. To retain that state when reopened, you would need to persist it before the dialog closes and load it when the dialog opens, like you are doing with the checked states of checkboxes currently. Using SharedPrefs for this is fine, since your list is not large.

However, from what I can see you are adding items to the list based on the checked states (which are already being stored). So you should be able to use them to construct the list without having to store the list too.

For example:

```
if (getFromSP("cb1")) {
    myList.add("'Accord','Avlon','Challenger'")
}
```

and similar for the other checkboxes. This can be done in `onCreateView` just after you `getFromSP` and use it to `setChecked`.